# Pixel accuracy off by 2 pixels

Tags: html, css

I've noticed when using ruler tools from my browser extensions (I've tried multiple) that pixel specifications are typically short by 2 pixels. After noticing this on a site I'm working on, I tried a very simple html page with a div specified with a width and height of 200px and no border or padding. Measuring it out afterwards across multiple browsers and with various ruler tools, the actual rendered box both width and height is 2 pixels shy of my css.

So, curious why this is. What contributes to the "physical" size of the box, screen resolution perhaps? Not the end of the world if this is really how it is, seeing as how it seems to be a consistent thing.

EDIT

Per the comments and reply, my code, very simple:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;background: red"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And I'm measuring from outside-to-outside. Like here:

[image]

Comment: Setting a `div` to have a `width` and `height` of `200px` works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xfNp8/

Comment: Gotta say I've never encountered this problem. Check to see that you're not adding a border, margin, padding, or anything that would shrink the size of the element you're concerned with.

Comment: @icktoofay, perhaps it is my display. I tried my ruler against your box from your link and get the same 2 pixels short. Also There's no css at all aside from my inline style on the div itself.

Comment: @wittyhandle: That shouldn't make any difference. Either way, it's definitely 200px wide for me. Try taking a screenshot and measuring it in some image editing program.

Comment: [Look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/pQ5v5/). The top box is 200x100. The bottom boxes are both 100x100. If CSS always made things 2px smaller in each direction, the right edges would not line up. (100 + 100 = 200, but 100 - 2 + 100 - 2 != 200 - 2)

Answer (score 2):

If the box you are drawing with your cursor starts *inside* the box you are measuring, it will be 2 pixels less than if the box you are using to measure starts *outside* the box you are measuring.

Here is a little graphic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

best is use reset css to ignore such issue

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/

Answer (score 0):

I just measured the height of the box above with the (freeware) pixel ruler I wrote, A Ruler for Windows, and it measured just fine as 200 pixels.

I'm a little confused by your box inside the big red box, but the inside box measures a width of 50 if you count the burgundy boarder as part of what needs to be measured.

Of note, with A Ruler for Windows (when it is horizontal) the line on the left edge of the ruler counts as pixel one, and if the ruler is set to a length of (for example) 200, the line on the right edge of the ruler counts as pixel 200.

In other words if you are measuring something that is, for example 3 pixels wide, you would see the 1 pixel on the left to start the ruler, only one pixel in the middle, and finally one pixel on the right to end the ruler.

This is done in this way to allow the ruler to be moved to the two edges of your screen and to have those pixels on the edges counted.

Would it be possible that the two pixels you seem to be shy are the two 1 pixel widths on either end of the ruler?

ref: [www.arulerforwindows.com](http://www.arulerforwindows.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'm chalking this up to browser weirdness. Taking screenshots of pages and comparing them in photoshop, they line up perfectly.